# Stack multiple columns of df in bar/col plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have the following df

```
df <- data.frame(genre = c("Thriller", "Horror", "Action"), europe = c(30, 35, 50), asia = c(20, 15, 25), america = c(50, 50, 25))

     genre europe asia america
1 Thriller     30   20      50
2   Horror     35   15      50
3   Action     50   25      25
```

I would like to get the plot

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer` to reshape your data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -1), aes(genre, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(color = "gray20") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(value, "%")), fontface = "bold", size = 5,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1ca4fc", "#fcad2a", "#595959"), 
                    name = "Continent") +
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you can further change colors/ordering however you'd like.

```
library(reshape2)
df_melt = melt(df, id.vars = "genre")

ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = genre, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(value, "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Edited to include labels.