# Stack multiple columns of df in bar/col plot and create %

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

A sequel to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64756050/13349937) question. I have the following df

```
df <- data.frame(genre = c("Thriller", "Horror", "Action"), europe = c(195, 210, 300), asia = c(130, 90, 150), america = c(325, 300, 150))

    genre europe asia america
1 Thriller    195  130     325
2   Horror    210   90     300
3   Action    300  150     150
```

I would like to get the plot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pivot long, calculate the proportions, the key is to make a label on the fly using paste :

```
df %>% 
pivot_longer(-genre) %>% 
group_by(genre) %>% 
mutate(p=100*value/sum(value)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=genre,y=p,fill=name)) + 
geom_col() + 
geom_text(aes(label=paste(p,"%","(",value,")")),
position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]